# Passing Parameter From a View Back To another View's UITableView's Cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

i have got two view.
First: FirstViewController
Second: SecondViewController

**FirstViewController** is my **UINavigationController**'s root controller and inside **FirstViewController** I ve got UITableView. When a cell is clicked in UITableView, the view is navigated to **SecondViewController**. Inside **SecondViewController** i have UILabel. I want to assign this UILabel's value to the cell which is clicked at FirstViewController ***when Back button is clicked in Navigation Bar***. What am i supposed to do to implement this?

I can pass value to SecondViewController from FirstViewController by creating:

SecondViewController *sv;
sv.somestring = someanotherstring;

but can not implement this at SecondViewController to pass the value to a NSString in FirstViewController.

Can u help me please?

Thank you.
ae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya , there is much a easy way to handle this.....

You can take a Global Variable

In your **Delegate.h** file declare your variable:

```
@interface Smoke_ApplicationAppDelegate : NSObject {

  UIWindow *window;
  UINavigationController *navigationController;
  NSString *messageString;  //This would be your String Variable
}
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *messageString;
```

Secondly in **Delegate.m** file

```
@implementation Smoke_ApplicationAppDelegate

@synthesize window; 
@synthesize navigationController; 
@synthesize messageString; // Synthesize it over here..
```

This is Done .Now you can use this String Variable in All/any class you want..

To use this Global Variable.

Just ***import you Delegate file make the obj*** of it....

```
import "DelegateFile.h"

@implementation About

DelegateFile *appDel;
```

Now in Your class.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];

appDel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

}
```

Now you can access it anywhere in your class by this Object:

```
appDel.messageString
```

Just follow my Steps Carefully , I am sure this is definitely going to help you.....

Have a easy life,

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer.Still you can do the same thing with other's way's too by making an Object of other class & using it by synthesize.

Answer (score 7):

The typical way to handle this in the iPhone SDK is to define a delegate protocol.  For instance:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate
- (void) viewControllerWillDisappearWithLabelText: (NSString*)text;
@end
```

Then you would add a `delegate` property to your `SecondViewController`, like:

```
//in the .h file
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    //declare instance variables
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

//in the .m file
@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate;

//[code...]
@end
```

Then you would update `FirstViewController` to implement the delegate protocol:

```
//in the .h file
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate> {
    //[instance variables]
}
//[methods and properties]
@end

//in the .m file
@implementation FirstViewController
//[code...]

- (void) viewControllerWillDisappearWithLabelText: (NSString*)text {
    //do whatever you need to do with the text
}

//[code...]
@end
```

...and to set the delegate field when `FirstViewController` creates the `SecondViewController`:

```
SecondViewController* sv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; 
sv.somestring = someanotherstring;
sv.delegate = self;
```

Finally, in `SecondViewController` you implement `viewWillDisappear` to be roughly like:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear: (bool)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate viewControllerWillDisappearWithLabelText: myLabel.text];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string (stringVal)in the appdeleage and set its propert as nonatomic and retain, synthesize it also.In the second view controller you can set the label value to the appdelegate string([appdelegate setStringVal:label.text];) .You can get this value in the first view controller and use it in table(NSString *localString=appdelegate.stringVal];).

All the best.